# Jquery Show Hide Div on Radio Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following radio buttons. On page load I want to hide all ordered lists. When I select radio with value age 40 i want to show list-group-1, when i select radio with value 50 I want to show list-group-2 and when I select radio with value 60 I want to display list-group-3. How can you do this with jquery?

```
<input type="radio" name="age" value="40">40
<input type="radio" name="age" value="50">50
<input type="radio" name="age" value="60">60



<ol class="list-group-1">
 <li class="line"></li>
<ol>

<ol class="list-group-2">
 <li class="line"></li>
</ol>

<ol class="list-group-3">
 <li class="line"></li>
</ol>
```

** EDIT **

Appreciate all the different solutions, but why wouldn't jquery toggle() method not work?

In the end this is what I used:

```
$(function() {
  $('*[class^="js-toggle-"]').hide();

  var myListRef = {'email':'email','tel':'tel','writing':'writing'}
  $('[name="contact"]').click(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $('.js-toggle-' + myListRef[$this.val()]).show();

     $.each( myListRef , function( key, value ) {
         if(value !== $this.val()) {
              $('.js-toggle-' + value).hide();
         }    
      });

  });

 $('#problem').change(function(){
    if($('#problem').val() == 'parcel') {
        $('.js-toggle-problem').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.js-toggle-problem').hide(); 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Do the lists stay visible when you select another radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("ol[class^='list-group-']").hide();
//$(".list-group-1").hide();
//$(".list-group-2").hide();
//$(".list-group-3").hide();

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  switch(this.value){
    case '40':
      $(".list-group-1").show();
      $(".list-group-2").hide();
      $(".list-group-3").hide();
      break;
    case '50':
      $(".list-group-1").hide();
      $(".list-group-2").show();
      $(".list-group-3").hide();
      break;
    case '60':
      $(".list-group-1").hide();
      $(".list-group-2").hide();
      $(".list-group-3").show();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="age" value="40">40
<input type="radio" name="age" value="50">50
<input type="radio" name="age" value="60">60



<ol class="list-group-1">
 <li class="line">test 1</li>
</ol>

<ol class="list-group-2">
 <li class="line">test 2</li>
</ol>

<ol class="list-group-3">
 <li class="line">test 3</li>
</ol>
```

Note: You asked in your comment about the right syntax to select all `<ol>` elements in one jQuery. The right syntax is `$("ol[class^='list-group-']").hide();`. I used it in my demo above and commented out the three equivalent lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $('ol').hide();
    var myListRef = {'40':'1','50':'2','60':3}
   $('[name="age"]').click(function() {
         $('.list-group-' + myListRef[$(this).val()]).show();
   });
});
```

Comment: is there a way to hide the ordered list using the class. something like `$('ol *[class*='list-group-']).hide()` cant seem to find the correct syntax?

Comment: you can get it but not directly as a selector, u need to run it as a loop. $('ol').forEach(function(){
if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('list-group-') == 0) {
//Your code here
}

} );

Comment: This would hide all classes that start with list-group wouldnt it `$('ol *[class^='list-group-']).hide()` ?

Comment: Sorry whats the full syntax please?

Comment: I am not sure about your solution. I can say the way that I did will work after you add $(this).hide() in place of "Your code here" commentline in my above comments.

Comment: Ok your code will show them but doesnt hide the other lists i.e. only one list group should show at a time?

Comment: Please add your query completely or else post it as a separate question.

Comment: @ozzii Yes, you're right, you can select them like that in one jQuery. The right syntax is `$("ol[class^='list-group-']").hide();` and I've used it in my answer for you as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution is a bit longer bit it's easier to understand what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/xrveLsc8/

CSS:

```
ol {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="age"]').click(function() {
        var lisGroup = null;

        switch (parseInt($(this).val())) {
            case 40:
                lisGroup = '.list-group-1';
                break;
            case 50:
                lisGroup = '.list-group-2';
                break;
            case 60:
                lisGroup = '.list-group-3';
                break;
        }

        $(lisGroup).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the position of `input` and `ol` elements correspond to each other in your scenario, the easiest and simplest way is to use `index()` for `input` and use the same to locate the corresponding `ol`.

```
$('ol').hide(); // Hide all ol's initially
$('input:radio').click(function()
{
    $('ol').hide(); // Hides all ol's - remove if not needed
    $('ol').eq($(this).index()).show(); - finds the corresponding index of ol and shows it.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f1sdptm4/1/

With this you may add as many input-radio button combos and never to have to revisit the script part.